# Lagrange remainder of Taylor series of $e^{xy}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

> Find the Peano remainder of second order Taylor series of $e^{xy}$ at $(0, 0)$.

*First approach.* Applying the one-variable Taylor series for $e^t$ where $t= xy$, the remainder is $\dfrac{e^{t_0}}{3!}(xy)^3$ for some $t_0$ such that $|t_0|<|xy|$.

*Second approach.* We calculate third order partial derivatives of $e^{xy}$:
$$f_{xxx}= y^3e^{xy}, f_{xxy} = (2y+xy^2)e^{xy}, f_{xyy} = (2x+x^2y)e^{xy}, f_{yyy}=x^3e^{xy}. $$
By the Taylor series for multivariable function, the remainder is $$\frac{1}{3!}\left(y_0^3e^{x_0y_0}\cdot x^3+3(2y_0+x_0y_0^2)e^{x_0y_0}\cdot x^2y+3(2x_0+x_0^2y_0)e^{x_0y_0} \cdot xy^2+x_0^3e^{x_0y_0} \cdot y^3\right)$$
for some $(x_0, y_0)$ such that $x_0^2+y_0^2 < x^2+y^2$.

What is the difference between results of the two approaches? Are they the same or different?

Thank you very  much.